# Почему функции wordpress не работают в mail.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на wordpress. Отправка почты через `ajax` в таком виде работает:

```html
<?php

$recepient = 'admin@yandex.ru';
// $recepient = get_bloginfo(); // Любая функция wordpress прервет выполнение программы

$siteName = 'siteName';
$name     = !empty($_POST['message_name'])     ? "Имя: "                 . trim($_POST['message_name'])     . "\n" : "";
$email    = !empty($_POST['message_email'])    ? "Email: "               . trim($_POST['message_email'])    . "\n" : "";

$pageTitle = "Заявка с сайта \"$siteName\"";

$message = "$name$email";

mail(
    $recepient,
    $pageTitle,
    $message,
    "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient"
);
```

Но стоит раскомментировать `get_bloginfo()`, как функция перестает работать.

**Важно: никакие функции `wordpress` не работают в данном файле**

Я проверял `echo get_bloginfo()` на соседнем файле-странице и получал ожидаемый результат - все работает.

Почему это не работает в файле `mail.php` и как сделать так, чтобы можно было при отправке почты в данном файле брать email админа и название сайта (данные wordpress)?

Comment: Даже если исправить видимую проблему этот код дыряв  и будет работать на большинстве хостингов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что все надо делать правильно. WordPress - довольно большая система, со своими правилами. [Почитайте на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html), как надо организовывать запросы ajax в WordPress.

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к функциям ядра WordPress. А кто его инициализировал и подключал все эти функции? Никто.

ajax - всего лишь http-запрос на сервер. Вы явно там указываете свой файл, который содержит код в вашем вопросе. Веб-сервер честно отрабатывает ваш запрос и передает этот файл на исполнение php. Никто из них знать ничего не знает о том, что где-то рядом лежит WordPress, который вы имели ввиду подключить.

Делайте всё как положено, и таких проблем возникать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Уже на столько вопросов моих ответили, прямо как наставник, а я все еще криво делаю :D

Comment: А никто ж не мешает делать прямо ))

Comment: Учусь) А что делать, через ошибки и косяки